# Where can i find the Linux counterparts for the Windows Console API functions?

Tags: c#, c, linux, mono, console

Where can i find the Linux (calling C function from Mono-C#) counterparts for the next Windows Console API functions:

- [ReadConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [WriteConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  - with mouse support in Terminal
- etc.

Comment: I would expect pinvoking some of the curses functions might get you what you want. Try looking through for example http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to try http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/.  I've not tried it myself but it looks like it supports windows and linux on top of .Net/Mono.

One of the more fun examples can be found [here](http://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/)

Looking at how this is put together it would save you having multiple console format implementations.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no ReadConsoleOutput functionality in this library :(